# AndroidでInputStreamをStringに変換しようとするとOOMが発生する

Tags: android, java

InputStreamをStringに変換しようとするとOutOfMemoryErrorが発生します。
変換しようとしているInputStreamはAndroidのプロジェクトのrawフォルダの中にあるバイナリファイル(5.5MB)を次のようにInputStreamに変換したものです。
OoMがスローされないよう改善できませんか？

```
InputStream is = this.getRawResouces().openRawResouce();
```

メモリが876MBの環境でテストしています。

## ソースコード

### readメソッドを使って書いたコード

```
static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
char[] buf = new char[512];
int numRead;
while (0 <= (numRead = reader.read(buf))) {
    builder.append(buf, 0, numRead);
}
    buf=null;
return builder.toString();//ココでOoM発生
}
```

## readLine

```
static String inputStreamToString(InputStream is){
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String b = null;
    try{
        while ((b=reader.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(b);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){

    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

### 呼び出し元のコード

```
 private void checkVersion() throws Throwable{
    //呼び出し元は、onResume()のonClick()
    InputStream versionStream=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.git);

    String verchecked=Event.convertInputStreamToString(versionStream);
    //ココでreadメソッドを使って書いたコードを使って変換しようとするが、OoM発生、スローされる
    versionStream.close();//closeは書いている
    java.lang.Process p = null;
    TextView vertext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.version);

    try{
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(verchecked+" version");
        verchecked=null;//vercheckedはもう使わないからnull
        InputStream returnVerison=p.getInputStream();//結果を返す
        p=null;//pはもう使わないからnullを代入
        String ver=Event.convertInputStreamToString(returnVerison);
        returnVerison.close();
        vertext.setText(ver);
        ver=null;
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        vertext.setText("取得失敗: "+e);
    }
    vertext=null;
}

 protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
      //このクラスはMainActivity(最初に呼び出されるActivity)から呼び出される
        Button Update=(Button) findViewById(R.id.UpdateButton);
        Update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1){
                    try{
                        checkVersion();
                    }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(GitUpdate.this,"取得失敗:"+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        });
```

## ヒープ

Android StudioでMemoryの様子を見てみました。一応画像貼っておきます。
[image]
へこんでいるところがInputStreamを変換したところです。
MB単位です。
`totalMemory(),MaxMemory()`
7 ,96

## スタックトレース

```
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:189)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at com.jimdo.solarand.git.GitUpdate.checkVersion(GitUpdate.java:153)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at com.jimdo.solarand.git.GitUpdate.access$1000009(GitUpdate.java)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at com.jimdo.solarand.git.GitUpdate$100000001.onClick(GitUpdate.java:50)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4487)
06-22 20:06:54.681 W/System.err(28046):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18746)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(Native Method)
06-22 20:06:54.691 W/System.err(28046):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## その他情報

解決を早めるために、[別サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/38726)にも投稿させて頂きました。

Comment: ストリームの入力になっているテキストサイズははどの程度でしょうか？また`InputStream`は適切に`close()`されていますか？入力がネットワークからであれば、コネクション周りの`close()`忘れの可能性を考慮に入れるといいと思います。

Comment: 初歩的な質問で申し訳ないですがバイナリファイルのテキストサイズってどうやって確認するのでしょうか(外部からダウンロードしたものを使っているため分からない)。ファイルサイズなら、5.5MBみたいです。

Comment: ファイルサイズが大きく見積もっても6MB程度という情報があれば大丈夫です。メモリが876MBとのことですが、実際の各アプリケーションに割り当てられるJavaヒープはもっと少ないです。ですが、6MBでOoMが起きるかというと微妙なので、リソースリーク（`close()`しているかどうか）を疑うか、ヒープダンプして調査するかっていう感じじゃないでしょうか。最終手段で`largeHeap`。いずれにしても、このコード自体を見ても、原因はわからなさそうです。

Comment: ヒープはAndroidなんでどんくらい割り当てられているのかわかりませんし、ヒープを沢山割り当てるのも出来ません。後close()もしています。

Comment: Androidが各アプリに割り当てるJavaヒープの量は`Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`で知ることができます（もしJavaヒープとNativeヒープについてご存知でなければ調べてみてください）。また、AndroidStudio1.5からはメモリプロファイラが強化されていますので、そちらを利用方法を調べてみてください。最後に、「エラーが発生しない」とされているコードは、`line`が固定値0なのでそもそもストリームから読み込んだデータを利用していません。`sb.append(b);`に修正する必要があります。

Comment: そういえば `maxMemory()`がありましたね。後エラーが発生しないコードについてもありがとうございます。取得しあた文字が一文字も無いことに気が付きいま原因を探していたところです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/38726　マルチポスト

Comment: @htb 削除した方がいいですか？

Comment: @sunsolar-arrow その必要はございません。別々のサイトで回答者が無意味な時間をかけないよう、リンクを張る程度の配慮をお願いしたいです。マルチポストについて調べておいてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論が出ました。バイナリデータを文字列に変換するのは**無理**です。
むりやり文字列に変換すると、1バイトのバイナリデータがで2、3バイト程の文字と認識される場合があり、二倍、三倍くらいのヒープが消費されるためです。
272shin16さんが言うには

> 最低でもヒープサイズが11MBは必要になるということには変わりないです。

とのことです。teratailでも

> バイナリデータを無理やり文字に変換しようとしていますから、 
>   1バイトのバイナリデータが2バイトの文字に変換される場合があり、最悪2倍のメモリを消費する結果となっているのではないかと思われます。

とのことです。
これでは空白ヒープを上回り、最終的にはOoMが発生という流れでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

もし5.5MBのサイズのファイルのすべての文字列が一行としてreadLineで読み込まれるのだとしたら、まずb:Stringにはおそらく11MBのヒープ確保が必要になります。
またStringBuilderのappendではchar配列に文字列を差し込む処理で一時的に、charとString双方を確保するために、サイズが2倍必要になっているのかもしれません（すみません、nativeのコードを見ましたがそこまで把握できず/ [たぶんここらへん](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/native/java_lang_String.cc)）

仮に22MBそこで必要になっているのだとしたら、上の画像にある75MBから空白Heap含めた約95MBを上回ってしまっているのでは？という仮定はできると思います。
ただ上記の画像では落ちてないっぽいので、この仮定の前提が違う気がしますけど。

※というか画像のonResumeにsleep書いてるのやばい気がしますけど…。もっと他に何かあるだろうという気がしてきますね…。

Comment: コードをみました。この場合でももし5.5MBのファイル読み込みをして入っているデータをString型に置き換えようとしているなら、最低でもヒープサイズが１１MBは必要になるということには変わりないです。そしてそれはOOMを起こす可能性があります。今回の問題は、他の処理で大量にヒープが消費されている状態で、この処理を呼び出すことでトドメを刺していることではないかと考えます。変数のスコープの確認、不要になったデータへの参照を開放、メモリリークの改善などを行い、できるだけヒープをミニマムになるようにし、全体としてメモリ効率が高くすることが解決策の様に思います。

Comment: 分かりました。思い当たるところは直します。

Answer (score 0):

readlineがいけないのかもしれません。
別方法のread等を使ってみてください。
readlineの対象の１行が巨大だった場合、読込時に連続した領域を確保できなくてＯＯＭが発生している可能性が考えられます。